# timestamp with time zone (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I have a field named 'timestamp_created' with field type `timestamp with time zone`.

I've set the postgrsql timezone to UTC with the command: `SET TIME ZONE UTC;`.

When I do the following command: `SELECT NOW();`, I get the timestamp in UTC, so this is correct (`2020-11-25 13:49:02.321437+00`).

I have a nodejs backend for my website, and I have a query to insert a record like this:

```
const query = "INSERT INTO table (id, value, timestamp_created) VALUES ($1, $2, NOW())``.
```

But when I check the inserted row, the timestamp in timestamp_created is in timezone UTC+01.

In my nodejs code (index.js), I have the following line: ``process.env.TZ = 'UTC';```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can try with `SELECT timestamp_created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` or even `SELECT to_char(timestamp_created AT TIME ZONE 'UTC','YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SSZ')`

Comment: What is the `TimeZone` value in the database? `timestamp with time zone` does not store the timezone it just converts inputted  values to `UTC` when it stores them. On retrieval it rotates them to what ever the `TimeZone` value is unless overridden.